# Symfony observer pattern - How to dispatch custom event when setting entity property?

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine, observer-pattern

Is there a way to dispatch a custom event every time a certain entity setter is called ?

I actually need to change some value of an unrelated entity, every time a certain entity property is changed. So in order to separate concerns and to decouple objects, I wanted to do this with the observer pattern. I don't want to do this in some doctrine event like 'preUpdate' or similar, as they only fire when the entity is flushed, but I need this value to change immediately to assure these two values are always in sync.

As it is bad practice to inject any service into the entity, I don't see how I could do that ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, it's very bad practice to inject service into the entity. 
I don't understand why you want to log change that will not be flushed to DB?

Comment: I did not say that it will not be flushed, I just said I need it to be in sync even if not "yet" flushed

Comment: You can wrap your entity into the custom service with event dispatcher injected. That service will dispatch custom events on property change.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I am using that entity in many places without any service wrapped around, so I was hoping that I would not have to change all of that ... I guess I have to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the **event dispatcher**:

The Event that will carry your information

```
class UpdateEntityEvent extends Event {
     private $myEntity;
     private $newValue;

     public function __construct(Entity $entity, Whatever $newValue){
         $this->myEntity = $entity;
         $this->newValue = $newValue;
    }
  // [...] getters
}
```

Your Listener

```
class UpdateMyEntityEventListener
{
    public function updateCertainProperty(UpdateMyEntityEvent $event)
    {
        // Do what you want here :D
    }
}
```

Some configuration

```
 kernel.listener.updateMyEntity:
     class: Acme\AppBundle\EventListener\UpdateMyEntityEventListener
     tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: updateMyEntity, method: updateCertainProperty }
```

We avoid using some hardcoded string, let's put the event name in a constant

```
class MyEntityEvents 
{
    const UPDATE = 'updateMyEntity';
}
```

Then in your Controller

```
public function updateAction()
{
    // [...]
    $event = new UpdateMyEntityEvent($entity, $whatever);
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch( MyEntityEvents::UPDATE, $event);
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you propose. But here is why this is not really a solution for me:

Comment: ... I have many controllers that update that property, will I have to add the event dispatch to all of them. What if I forget one, or what if I code a new one some time from now, will I remember to do that ??

Comment: I could say the same when using the persist/flush method: I have many controllers which update my entity, what if I forgot to flush? WIll I remember to do that? :p. You could use another service like EntityManager with a method `updateMyEntity()` which keep this logic inside

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the observer pattern, you will have to implement it yourself in some way. As you pointed out, Doctrine will compute the changeset of your entity only when a flush operation is triggered and not before. That being said, it happens that Doctrine proposes [alternative tracking policies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html). The `NOTIFY` tracking policy behaviour relies exactly on what you wish to achieve.

I am not suggesting that you should change the tracking policy of your entity but you could take advantage of the existing interfaces to implement your observer pattern. To do so, as explained [in this section of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify), your entity being observed needs to implement the [NotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.NotifyPropertyChanged.html) interface.

From there you could implement the [PropertyChangedListener](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.PropertyChangedListener.html) interface directly in the other entity (or use a specific service that would add itself as listener of your entity in the `postLoad` event for example ?). Here it mainly depends on the relation between your entities and how you can attach your listener to the entity implementing `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Note that if you do this, the `UnitOfWork` of Doctrine will automatically hook itself as a listener of your entity but it will still rely on automatic changeset computation as long as you don't add the `@ChangeTrackingPolicy("NOTIFY")` annotation.

Comment: Sounds great. But how and when to add the listener ? Or can I catch the event in a doctrine subscriber ? How ?

Comment: Well as I said, it depends on the relationship between your two entities. What is it exactly, is there an association?

Comment: No association. I have an ecommerce bundle with order and orderItem entities, and now I wanted to add a stock system to it ( decoupled ). The stock system needs to be informed of any quantity change of an oderItem.

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling that approach this the wrong way ... but many thanks for your help.